# Get image in http payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, blob, jpeg

I am trying to return image as response to http POST request. Image should be returned in payload of http response. Response string:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

When convert this string to Blob and save, result file is not valid. Converting code:

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: headers['content-type'] });
```

Comment: What is `data` and how are you getting it? Please include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly find out reason. To download blob you have to specify that response payload is binary.
Example for axios:

```
axios.post(endpoint, formData, {
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
```